# VS 2008 Website project file

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Hi All I have a VS 2008 ASP.NET solution with website project and many other projects. I've had to add new items to the Web Stite part of the solution. I added them (new items) in Visual Studio that part is OK. Now I need to check in my changes to Version Control. I added new files. But I think I also need to check in a .csproj file which has info about the new item I added. And here lays the problem. I found the sln file which lists all the .csproj files, but I added the new items to the Web Site project and there isn't a .csproj file for it anywhere? The .sln file does no list the items which are part of this project so where is this info in? What file do I need to check in for the project to know about those new items I added to it. I've been pulling my hair for a couple of hours. Please help

Comment: Please see below part of the sln file:

Comment: Website projects don't have a project file, only Web Application Projects.

Comment: Thanks Mark. But how does VS know a file is part of the project or not? When you add new item to the project you'd think it stores this info somewhere?

Comment: It does with most project types except the website project. The website project includes everything in it with the exception of the things you tell it to exclude. Since it doesn't have a project file, it does this by adding .exclude onto any file you want to exclude from the website.